# set-mailcontact not removing smtp addresses

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, email

Hopefully this is a simple one...

Trying to remove **unwanted entries** in the **proxyAddresses** from AD objects of type **mail contact**. I am logged into an exchange server using the exchange shell; no problems there. Here's my one-liner that doesn't seem to do anything:

```
set-mailcontact -identity Joe_User_Contact -emailAddresses @{remove="Joe_User_Contact@unwantedDomain.com"}
```

No errors; but when I browse to the AD object and look at "proxyAddresses", the unwanted entry still exists.

I have also tried:

```
set-mailcontact -identity Joe_User_Contact -emailAddresses @{remove="smtp:Joe_User_Contact@unwantedDomain.com"}
```

To no avail. Does this command not actually do what I think it's supposed to do?

Thanks!

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? If your domain has multiple domain controllers, you'll have to wait until the change replicates to the other DC's.

Comment: I just checked again and It's been over an hour; definitely way longer than our DC replication settings. Good thought though!

Comment: I gave this a try myself and it works just fine. I assume you're not getting any errors? Are you getting any output at all?

Comment: To help with testing, you can specify the `-DomainController` to a specific DC so you can verify on that same DC right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command should do exactly what you want, I use it on a regular basis.

First, I recommend you to check, that the cmdlet really works, try to add an alias.

Second, it something wrong with the connection to server, try doing

`Connect-ExchangeServer YourServer -AllowClobber`

Third, check that EmailAddressPolicy doesn't prevent you from removing alias (check there policies, especially the lowest - default one) .

You can simply disable it:

`Set-MailContact joe@contoso.com -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false`

Also you can set EmailAddresses attribute with this pattern:

`Set-MailContact joe@contoso.com -EmailAddresses 'SMTP:joe@contoso.com'`

This one will delete all other aliases except the one you wrote (it may require you to disable emailaddress policy).

Comment: I will try the -emailAddressPolicyEnabled setting next time I am onboarding a new user. Till then, I can't test this yet... but when I do I'll see if that works and mark as solution.

Comment: ok, let me know if it will work and mark the answer as correct, please

Comment: haven't had a chance to test this yet.. when I do I'll let you know!

Comment: Guess what: I just tested this very old ticket (3 months old) and, well, this time it just worked. I ran it from the exchange powershell; and it worked like it was supposed to. I am trying to remember: I may have tried to run it in regular powershell but connecting via sessions or something. This just worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @Pink great! Nice to know everything's working as expected) :)